# How to store the return value of os.system that it has printed to stdout in python?

Tags: python

I am writing a python script which checks for number of active connections for a particular IP / port. For this I use os.system( 'my_command') to grab the output. os.system returns the exit status of the command I've passed it (0 means the command returned without error).
How can I store this value which os.system throws to STDOUT in a variable ? So that this variable can used later in the function for counter.
Something like subprocess, os.popen can help. Can someone suggest ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('my_command', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, error = p.communicate()
```

Comment: Would not the third line you mentioned be under parenthesis ? Like, (out, error) = p.communicate() and then say print "the result is: ", out

Comment: No, in Python, you don't need the parenthesis. Tuples can be implicitly created and automatically packed and unpacked. Yes, you can then do `print 'The output was', out, 'and the error was', error`

Comment: OK, got that. Is this is the right syntax to execute the following netstat command -> result = subprocess.Popen(["netstat -plant | awk \'{print $4}\' | grep %s:%s | wc -l' %(ip,port)"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr= subprocess.PIPE)  ? I get an error : File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1202, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Why am I getting so ?

Comment: Please edit and surround code with backticks ``` so it's readable.

Comment: try this `result = subprocess.Popen('''sh -c "netstat -plant | awk \'{print $4}\' | grep %s:%s | wc -l' %(ip,port)"''')` Edit: or try it with `shell=True` as @Jakob-Bowyer suggested below. Needed because you're not just running one command, but instead are using the pipe `|` feature of the shell.

Comment: ``` result = subprocess.Popen(["netstat -plant | awk \'{print $4}\' | grep %s:%s | wc -l' %(ip,port)"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr= subprocess.PIPE) ``` I am accepting IP & Port as raw input from user.

Comment: Ah, then you want `result = subprocess.Popen('''netstat -plant | awk '{print $4}' | grep %s:%s | wc -l''' % (ip, port), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)` If this solves your problem, please accept my answer.

Comment: It worked this time, but, I am not getting the value printed in variable "out" when I say ``` out, error = result.communicate()  print "the connections are: ", out ```

Comment: What do you get when you do just `print subprocess.Popen('ls | cat', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()`? Something like `('DLLs\nDoc\nLICENSE.txt\nLib\nNEWS.txt\nPIL-wininst.log\nREADME.txt\nRemovePIL.exe\nRemovenumpy.exe\nRemovepywin32.exe\nRemovesetuptools.exe\nScripts\nTools\ninclude\nlibs\nnumpy-wininst.log\npython.exe\npython.exe.self\npythonw.exe\npythonw.exe.bak\npywin32-wininst.log\nsetuptools-wininst.log\ntcl\nw9xpopen.exe\n', '')` ?

Answer (score 18):

```
a=os.popen("your command").read()
```

new result stored at variable `a` :)

Comment: The correct one did not worked for me but this one was perfect!

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('my_command', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out, error = p.communicate()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
netstat -plant | awk '{print $4}' | grep %s:%s | wc -l
```

You can use Python to do the splitting, grepping and counting:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['netstat', '-plant'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

num_matches = 0

host_and_port = "%s:%s" % (ip, port)

for line in process.stdout:
    parts = line.split()
    if parts[3] == host_and_port: # or host_and_port in parts[3]
        num_matches += 1


print num_matches
```

Comment: This also solves my problem ; but @agf 's answer was a one liner