# How to get the output from os.system()?

Tags: python, subprocess, os.system

I want to get output from `os.system("nslookup google.com")` but instead I always get `0`, when printing it. Why is this, and how can I fix this? (Python 3, Mac)

(I looked at [How to store the return value of os.system that it has printed to stdout in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746126/how-to-store-the-return-value-of-os-system-that-it-has-printed-to-stdout-in-pyth) - But I didn't understand it ~ I'm new to python)

Comment: Python's `os.system("ls")` only returns the exit_code for `ls` which is a unix integer status from the operating system for the process.  0 here means "no-error".  Both the stdout and stderr of os.system is piped into your python program's stdout and stderr.  So either you re-implement this stdout redirection manually, or use a different python function that does this work automatically for you, one example of many being `subprocess`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess
print(subprocess.check_output(['nslookup', 'google.com']))
```

If the return code is not zero it will raise a `CalledProcessError` exception:

```
try:
    print(subprocess.check_output(['nslookup', 'google.com']))
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
    print(err)
```

[os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os.system#os.system) only returns the exit code of the command. Here `0` means success. Any other number stands for an operating-system-dependent error. The output goes to stdout of this process. [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) intends to replace `os.system`.

[subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) is a convenience wrapper around [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) that simplifies your use case.

Comment: It works. But could you explain why os.system(command) doesn't print output? (I'm new to Python)

Comment: os.system(command) prints output of command to the console, but it does not capture it! For example, files = os.system("ls") does not store the result in files.

Comment: Use `subprocess` not `os.system`.

Comment: I keep getting `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:` with subprocess

Comment: Try `shell=True` as argument.

Comment: In some more detail, you want `subprocess.check_output(["ls", "-l"])` or `subprocess.check_output("ls -l", shell=True)`. If you try `subprocess.check_output("ls -l")` without `shell=True`, Python will look for a command named literally `ls -l` (like literally, `/usr/local/bin/"ls -l"`) and, of course, not finding it. (These things work differently on Windows, to the point where writing `subprocess` code which is properly OS-independent is challenging.) [You should generally avoid `shell=True` if you can.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)